# Scraping Imprints from Websites

Tags: screen-scraping

here is a very detailed explanation of my problem, you will find at the bottom the summarization.

Long explanation:

---

so I am an complete beginner with software, so that´s why I ask you for some recommandations.

I build a very simple Scraper + Python script. The goals where the following:

1. Be able to scrape every url based on a set of keywords (e.g. "more qualified leads"
2. Be able to scrape the link to the imprint (e.g. https://www.website.com/imprint)
3. Be able to scrape all the informations from the imprint (e.g. company name etc.)
4. Be able to scrape only the most important informations (e.g. company name, ceo, phone number and E-mail)

So I was able to do step 1-3 with python (which I am really proud of, because I always thought I was too stupid for software lol)

But now I am stuck at stage 4.
I have a .csv with 245 links to the imprint and ALL informations from the imprint.

I tried to give ChatGPT the file, but since imprints tend to be overwhelmingly long, due to German laws, GPT is not able to extract the information (GPT always gives me the error "exceedance of length).

Do you guys have any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Here´s what I already tried:
Build simple regex with GPT (didn´t work, because sometimes the imprint doesn´t have the word "ceo".
Chunk the size of the document and try the GPT 4 Model (didn´t work, because exceedance of length)
Cry in my bedroom (didn´t work either)

The only vilable solution I found was using the openai playground, but since I don´t have enough money, i need a different solution.

Big thanks to your help!

Short summary:

- How do I extract from the imprint the most important data (Ceo Name, Phone Number, Company Number, E-Mail) without paying money? Regex didn´t work very well

Thanks!